# Angularjs data-ng-repeat is not working

Tags: html, angularjs, dom

I have following code, and let you know that i am new to angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <!-- <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>-->
    <title>Angular js</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-init="names=['Ran','Run','Run']">

    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="personName in names">{{personName}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no value shown from the names in li .....
any Help or suggestion to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open console of your browser, you can see error:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. 

Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: personName in ['Ran','Run','Run'], Duplicate key: string:Run
```

You have two same items in array (Run).

Delete last "Run" from array, and it will work fine.

Please, see:
[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2ehT9ENc1uBr0gABaLx?p=preview)

Comment: Or add 'track by $index' to the end of the repeat expression

Answer (score 2):

Please remove one `'Run'` from your `data-ng-init`

And it will work fine..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
    <!-- <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>-->
    <title>Angular js</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-init="names=['Ran','Run']">

    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="personName in names">{{personName}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script src="JS/angular-1.2.10.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```